# Select input where click event scrolls through set of defined values rather than opening up a drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a form element that does the same as `<select>` however from a UX perspective I simply want to be able to click/tap (preferably cyclically) through the set values (of which there will be four). So instead of the click opening up a drop down, it simply changes to the next value. Staying away from the UI imposed by the `<select>` tag is also important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/R78ZB/1/).

you create array with your values, and on click cycle through its values

```
           var array = [ 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4' ];

            $('#input').click(function(e){
                        var currValue = e.currentTarget.value;
                        var valueIndex = array.indexOf(currValue);
                        var arrayLength = array.length-1;

                        if(valueIndex != arrayLength)
                        {
                           $('#input')[0].value = array[valueIndex + 1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#input')[0].value = array[0];
                        }
             })
```

Comment: A bit confusing naming the variable array since it is an array, but this worked, thanks.

Comment: This works well until I try to reset the form, the values don't scroll in the correct order and occasionally a field will get stuck on one value?

Comment: please make a fiddle or at least show some code... cant tell what the problem could be without seeing code

Answer (score 0):

If you want, use Javascript or jQuery to define an array with those values. 
On click/tap, increment the index corresponding the selected value that from array. And when the index is array.length-1 (last one), reset it to 0.
Also, don't forget to assign the current array[index] value to your element. It can be a text input or a div.